Azure DevOps agent pool: How do I demand a specific net framework SDK capability?
We run self-hosted agents for our dev.azure.com pipelines. Some projects require specific NetFramework or NetCore versions but we don't want to install 20 years of old versions on all agent machines. (There are lots of SDK versions).
I can see that agent capabilities and demands provide the functionality to make sure a build is only run on a capable agent.
But how do I specify a demand for a specific NetFramework SDK version e.g. 4.8.1? I can't find a list of well known capability names that an agent might report.

No sure whether some of your agents have such capabilities as those of one of my agent's in the Default self-hosted pool below. If not, you may add a user-defined capablity to demand the agent job to run on the expected agents.

Taking my YAML pipeline for example, either agent job managed to pick up the expected agents.
jobs:
- job: ReferenceSystemCapabilities
  pool: 
    name: Default
    demands:
    - Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT
    - DotNetFramework_4.8.0
    - DotNetFramework_4.8.0_x64
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
      Get-ItemProperty -Name Version,Release -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
      Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
      Select-Object PSChildName, Version, Release

- job: ReferenceUserDefinedCapabilities
  pool: 
    name: Default
    demands:
    - DotNetFrameworkVersion -equals 4.8.0
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
      Get-ItemProperty -Name Version,Release -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
      Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
      Select-Object PSChildName, Version, Release



Thanks. The syntax for how to demand DotNetFramework_4.8.0 is half of what I need. Do I understand right that the best way you know to discover what system capabilities might be called is to look at existing agents and see what they declare?

But sadly I have a further hurdle. Possibly I need a different question: An agent machine with NetFramework SDK 4.8.1 installed only reports a capability of 4.8.0 and doesn't distinguish itself from a machine with just framework 4.8.0. But my machine with net4.8.0 installed fails to build a project with <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>

I see that the user-defined capabilities is actually very easy to manage so yes this would work.

Hi @ChrisFCarroll, Thanks for your taking time to share your insights. Actually if our agent machine(s) installed new software, we usually needed to restart the agent service (for Windows) or run the env.sh script (for Linux) to have the new capabilities scanned and updated. We could first check the updates on that agent machine environment and then check if those new tools were synchronized to agent capabilities tab, which I think should be a more user-friendly way to help monitor and maintain our agents.

And indeed. user-defined capabilities are convenient for us to pick up the expected agents when there are no well-known capability names populated.

Hope the information helps. Would you consider the query in this post resolved? Appreciate your sharing.

The resolution I'm hoping for is that there is a list of known system capabilities and that it includings one for Net SDK 4.8.1 :-) If there isn't any such, then yes, I will shortly accept this answer.

Yes, I agree. Have you got a chance to check if there are any updates in your machine environment by the way? I am not so familiar with the DotNetFramework installation as Azure DevOps, but as far as I understand, NetFx 4.8.1 should be updated in the machine local environment before being scanned and synchronized to Azure DevOps. I am not sure but hope uninstallation of 4.8.0 is not required because that could incur extra works. >_<!


we don't want to install 20 years of old versions on all agent machines

I had a similar problem in one of my previous roles - there were both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects.
We decided against using demands: all build agents running in a specific agent pool were able to run any build in that pool. This made things simple in terms of maintenance (less build agent types), and it prevented having underutilized build agents waiting for the few builds that would use a very specific (and old) version of the .NET Framework or .NET Core.
Regarding .NET Framework, we installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 including the following .NET Framework targeting packs:

4.6.2
4.7
4.7.1
4.7.2
4.8
4.8.1

Regarding .NET Core, we recommended developers to use the UseDotNet@2 task - example:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '3.1.x'

This solves the problem of installing multiple SDKs. Also, using wildcards ensures that the latest version of the SDK is used in the pipelines, as soon as it's available.
